Timelike geodesics in double null coordinates
Suppose we work with the line element
$$ \mathrm{d}s^2 =-f(u,v) \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v + r(u,v)^2 \mathrm{d}\theta^2+  r(u,v)^2\sin^2\theta \mathrm{d}\varphi^2 \,,$$
where $f(u,v)$ is some function and $r$ is radius of 2-spheres. I want to write a tangent to radial timelike geodesics with respect to the above line element.
Let coordinate $u$ be a parameter on these geodesics so that the integral curves can be written as $x^\alpha = (u, v=V(u),0,0)$ where $V(u)$ is given as follows. The tangent is
$$ l^\alpha = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\alpha }{\mathrm{d} u } =(1, V'(u), 0,0 ) \,.$$
We have from the normalization that $g_{\alpha \beta} l^\alpha l^\beta = -f(u,v)V'(u) =-1$. Thus the tangent is rewritten to
$$ l^\alpha = (1, \frac{1}{f(u,v)},0,0) $$
However, when I calculate the four accelaration (I use OGRe package), I have
$$ l^\alpha \nabla_\alpha l^\beta =(\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u} 1/f(u,v),-\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u} 1/f(u,v)^2,0,0) $$
Hence, the tangent does not satisfy $l^\alpha \nabla_\alpha l^\beta =\kappa l^\beta $ where $\kappa$ is some function. In other words, the geodesic equation for arbitrary parametrization is not satisfied.
My question: Does it mean that I cannot write a tangent to timelike geodesics with double null coordinates $u,v$? When one tries with auxillary parameter, say $t$ so that the curve is $x^\alpha =(u(t),v(t),0,0)$, the similar problems arise.
